# Examples of 2D side-scrollers that achieve open non-linear feel?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

I'm working on a 2.5D platformer prototype that aims for an open feel while maintaining familiar core mechanics.

Now, there's some obvious challenges with creating a non constricted feel in a spatially constricted environment. What I'm interested in, is examples of how game designers deal with the *"here's a level, beat the bad guys/puzzles to get to the next level"* design that seems so natural to most platformers (eg. Mario/Braid/Pid/Meat Boy to name a few).

Some ideas for achieving openness I've come across include:

- One obvious successful example is **Terraria**, which achieves openness simply through complexity and flexibility of the game-system
- Another example that comes to mind is **Cave Story**. Game is non-linear, offers multiple choices and side-stories
- **Mario**, **Rayman** and some other 'classics' with a top-down level selection. I actually really dislike this as it never did anything for me emotionally and just seems like a bit of a lazy way to do things.

Note: I've not actually had much experience with most of the 'classical' console platformers, apart from the obvious Marios/Zeldas/Metroids, since I've grown up on adventure games. By that I mean, it's entirely possible that I simply missed some games that solve the problem really well and are by some considered obvious 'classics'.

Comment: Check out Metroid Zero Mission, if you can. The game has a linear "default" path, but also was designed to include paths for much more advanced players (including dramatically changing the boss order), so-called, "Sequence Breaking".

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned Metroid in your last paragraph, but I would point to that game as the best example of an open-feeling 2D side scroller. Castlevania II also did this well (the others were more linear).

Comment: Why is this an answer and not a comment? You didn't explain how this game achieved its "open-feeling", nor did you give any references to people/blogs that explain it.  Would I have to play the whole game to understand your answer?

Comment: The question asks "give me examples". You can argue that the initial question is kinda poor, but this is certainly an answer to that question. I did in fact make this a comment at first, but switched it to an answer when I reflected on what the question asks. I also set my answer to "community wiki" because of what you said, it's just listing examples without any explanation. Is there a way to set the entire thread to community wiki?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best platformers I've ever played, [Shadow Complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Complex).  They built a giant 2.5D environment, and put in events that advance a plot.  But the player is utterly free to explore.  A player receives "experience" perks from playing the game enough, such as unlimited special weapons and tools.  And those allow a player even more freedom on subsequent playthroughs.